# Spark: Disconnected from Spark cluster! Waiting for reconnection

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Folks!

I am attempting to move Spark processing into cluster (Standalone). Previously, jobs were running successfully over cluster set up with *1 Worker node + Master on the same machine*. For example one of the jobs was running without any issues on *4gb and 2 cores*. The same with *local[*]* mode.

Now I set up the cluster in Kubernetes with *24.0 GB RAM and 6 cores - 3 Workers + Master*. And getting errors. For that simple job I am using all of the resources available in cluster.

Spark 2.2.0,Client mode.

```
spark-submit \
  --name RSS_Analysys\
  --class org.MainClass \
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Ddata=file:///aws/efs/data/"\
  --conf spark.executor.memory=8g\
  --conf spark.executor.cores=2\
  --master spark://AWS-ELB:7077\
  --deploy-mode client \
  --packages com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5\
file:///aws/efs/app/rss_app.jar
```

Driver output:

```
17/07/20 16:42:13 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 199.0 in stage 95.0 (TID 4017) in 4 ms on 172.12.0.1 (executor 2) (200/200)
17/07/20 16:42:13 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 95.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/07/20 16:42:13 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 95 (head at RSSProcessor.scala:76) finished in 0.670 s
17/07/20 16:42:13 INFO DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
17/07/20 16:42:13 INFO DAGScheduler: running: Set(ShuffleMapStage 96)
17/07/20 16:42:13 INFO DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ResultStage 97)
17/07/20 16:42:13 INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
17/07/20 16:42:25 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connection to 172.12.0.1:7077 failed; waiting for master to reconnect...
17/07/20 16:42:25 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Disconnected from Spark cluster! Waiting for reconnection...
17/07/20 16:42:26 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on 172.12.0.2: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/07/20 16:42:26 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on 172.12.0.3: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 0 (epoch 29)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 0 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/07/20 16:42:26 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_9_0 !
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(0, 172.12.0.2, 42948, None)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 0 successfully in removeExecutor
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Shuffle files lost for executor: 0 (epoch 29)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 93 is now unavailable on executor 0 (124/200, false)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 95 is now unavailable on executor 0 (126/200, false)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 94 is now unavailable on executor 0 (0/1, false)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 92 is now unavailable on executor 0 (0/1, false)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 1 (epoch 35)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(1, 172.12.0.3, 37556, None)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 1 successfully in removeExecutor
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Shuffle files lost for executor: 1 (epoch 35)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 91 is now unavailable on executor 1 (0/1, false)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 93 is now unavailable on executor 1 (65/200, false)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 95 is now unavailable on executor 1 (41/200, false)
17/07/20 16:42:26 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 2 on 172.12.0.1: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/07/20 16:42:26 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 96.0 (TID 3617, 172.12.0.1, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 2 (epoch 41)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 2 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(2, 172.12.0.1, 33264, None)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 2 successfully in removeExecutor
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Shuffle files lost for executor: 2 (epoch 41)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 93 is now unavailable on executor 2 (0/200, false)
17/07/20 16:42:26 INFO ShuffleMapStage: ShuffleMapStage 95 is now unavailable on executor 2 (0/200, false)
17/07/20 17:11:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_50_piece0 on 172.12.0.4:36275 in memory (size: 12.1 KB, free: 366.2 MB)
17/07/20 17:11:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_45_piece0 on 172.12.0.4:36275 in memory (size: 5.5 KB, free: 366.2 MB)
17/07/20 17:11:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_49_piece0 on 172.12.0.4:36275 in memory (size: 12.1 KB, free: 366.2 MB)
```

Interesting, that 12 seconds passed before error (Maybe timeout settings required?)

```
17/07/20 16:42:13 INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
17/07/20 16:42:25 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connection to 172.12.0.1:7077 failed; waiting for master to reconnect...
```

Before, I see that some stages are passed.
Any help or advise are highly appreciated.

Comment: can you ssh without passwords to all the nodes?